# In Angular, how can I tell between a programmatic and user click?

Tags: angular, click, dom-events

Let's say I have a simple

```
<li (click)="clicked($event)">click me</li>
```

How can I then tell in the function if the event was fired programatically or by the user ?

It's possible to gather that with jQuery but I had no chance on doing it only with js.

Comment: how to to fire it programatically?

Comment: I retrieve only a https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_mouseevent.asp event, nothing I can retrieve I think

Comment: I'm doing a simple element.click()

Comment: inspect event objects in both cases, they should be different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the [event.isTrusted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property to determine how the `click` event was generated:

> The `isTrusted` read-only property of the `Event` interface is a boolean
>   that is true when the event was generated by a user action, and false
>   when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via
>   dispatchEvent.

```
clicked(e: Event) {
  console.log(e.isTrusted ? "Clicked by user" : "Clicked programmatically");
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mc5wkc) for a demo.